# Couldnt find Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]Im getting this error in my my controller. It can't find the products id. Not to sure why it's getting an error.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:index, :new, :create]
   before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
     @products = current_user.products
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = current_user.products.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params)

      if @product.save
        redirect_to listing_products_path(@product), notice: "Saved..."
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
        render :new
      end
  end

  def update
      if @product.update(product_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
      end
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:description, :features, :listing, :location, :photo_upload, :pricing)
    end
end
```

I a user has to be signed in order to create a product. In my models i have a products belongs_to user and User has_many products

Comment: What error – exactly – do you get? On which line? Please provide the full error message and the stack trace. What request do you send to the server that triggers that error? Please show the corresponding entries from your log file.

Comment: @spickermann i have added a picture above. Im trying to redner the products/new page to create a new product but it throws this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load the product with an id from the params before your `index` action. But `index` routes usually do not provide any `params[:id]`.

To fix this bug just change

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

to

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Answer (score 0):

Id No need for index action because this display  list of All records  change

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

To

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```